# how to show a field in oracle reports at the bottom of the last page which is placed outside the border

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

how to show a field in oracle reports at the bottom of the last page which is placed outside the border

Answer (score 1):

A trivial answer is: place it outside the border.

I presume you already did that and encountered problems. It would really help if you specified which one(s).

The most usual error is that you're referencing a column at a **wrong frequency**, i.e. you can't just "move" it outside of its parent frame. (I guess that the frame is what you call a "border".) If that's so, well, you can't do that.

One way out is to create a new column (in the Data Model layout editor) (be it a formula or a placeholder column) which doesn't belong to any group, but is independent. Then you can place it anywhere you want.

---

If, on the other hand, you do have a *formula* (or *placeholder*, or *summary*) column and "border" you mentioned is the **margin**, then - while in Paper Layout editor - click the "Margin" icon in the toolbar to switch to ... well, *margin* layout editor. Now place that field anywhere you want.

---

Or, did you try to move the field but frames were resized and other fields moved along with the movement of the field you're moving? Pay attention to "Flex" and "Confine" ON/OFF buttons in the toolbar as they make the difference.

---

If none of above, what is your situation, then?